# Эффект при наведении на изображение

Tags: css

Никто не поделиться ссылкой на туториал? Вот что нужно: http://ssmaker.ru/673d0102.jpg

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Такой эффект можно сделать примерно так: http://jsfiddle.net/IonDen/d3qpgp4y/

```
<div class='test'>
    <div class='test-caption'>
        <div class='test-icon'></div>
    </div>
</div>
```

CSS:

```
.test {
    position: relative;
    width: 200px;
    height: 200px;
    background: #000;
}
.test-caption {
    position: absolute;
    left: 0;
    right: 0;
    bottom: 0;
    height: 50px;
    background: rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.5);

    transition: all 250ms cubic-bezier(0.455, 0.030, 0.515, 0.955);
    transition-timing-function: cubic-bezier(0.455, 0.030, 0.515, 0.955);
}

.test:hover .test-caption {
    height: 100%;
}

.test-icon {
    position: absolute;
    top: 50%; left: 50%;
    width: 20px; height: 20px;
    transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
    border-radius: 50%;
    background: #f00;
}
```

Анимации можно настроить с помощью этого конструктора анимаций: http://matthewlein.com/ceaser/ или этого плагина: [Animate.css](https://daneden.github.io/animate.css/)